# Executing multiple events JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Given a page with 2 input text fields and a button:

```
<form action="#" method="post"  id="form_register">
    <input type="text" name="username_input" id="username_input">
    <input type="text" name="password_input" id="password_input">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

And given the following JS script:

```
$("#username_input").blur(function(){  
   //do something 1
});

$("#form_register").submit(function(){
   //do something 2
});
```

Whenever I select (focus) the "#username_input" and try to click on the button to submit the form, only "do something 1" is executed. However I wish I could execute first "do something 1" and after that "do something 2". Is it possible?

Comment: if your "do something" is just `console.log('something 1');` and `console.log('something 2');` - do both get logged to the console? because your code snippet does both for me

Comment: What's in `do something 1`? Maybe it's doing something that's preventing the other event from triggering.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#username_input").blur(function(){  
   //do something 1
   doSomething2();
});
function doSomething2(){
   //do something 2
}
$("#form_register").submit(doSomething2);
```

Comment: This way I will execute 'do something2' whenever bluer happens, I need to execute 'do something2' only if $("#form_register").submit event is triggered.

Comment: @Ihidan your question wasn't clear. If that's what you want, then you already have it in the question as described by Jaromanda X